# How to get child xml data from xml file in android?

Tags: android, xml, listview

Can any one give me Java code to get a single child XML data from XML file and print it in `listview` in android?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at 
XmlPullParserhttp://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Theres a straightforward example in there

To get this data into a ListView you will need to read the xml into an ArrayAdapter and use this to populate the list view

Comment: can you exaplain me with sample code....assume                          <Table>
<Cust_Name>Sample name</Cust_Name>
<Order_No>Sample number</Order_No> </Table> this is that xml data which i am going to display it in listview